# How to Include Files by ID: MY shop the LAST Setting

Tags: php, html, select, include, echo

My website the products are identified by the msql id that dynamically loads each page

```php
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once('./inc/config.php');    
    require_once('./inc/helpers.php');  
    
    if(isset($_GET['product']) && !empty($_GET['product']) && is_numeric($_GET['product']))  
    {
        $sql = "SELECT p.*,pdi.img from tenis_femininos p
            INNER JOIN tenis_feminios_images pdi ON pdi.product_id = p.id WHERE pdi.is_featured =:featured AND p.id =:productID";
        $handle = $db->prepare($sql);
        $params = [
                ':featured'=>1,
                ':productID' =>$_GET['product'],
            ];
        $handle->execute($params);
        if($handle->rowCount() == 1 )
        {
            $getProductData = $handle->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $imgUrl = PRODUCT_IMG_URL.str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($getProductData ['sku']))."/".$getProductData ['img'];
        }
        else
        {
            $error = '404! No record found';
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $error = '404! No record found';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart']) && $_POST['add_to_cart'] == 'add to cart')
    {
        $productID = intval($_POST['product_id']);
        $productQty = intval($_POST['product_qty']);
        $entraSku = validate_input($_POST['pega_sku']); 
        $entraCor = validate_input($_POST['pega_cor']); 
        $entraSize = validate_input($_POST['pega_size']); 
        
        $sql = "SELECT p.*,pdi.img from tenis_femininos p
            INNER JOIN tenis_feminios_images pdi ON pdi.product_id = p.id WHERE pdi.is_featured =:featured AND p.id =:productID";

        $prepare = $db->prepare($sql);
        
        $params = [
                ':featured'=>1,
                ':productID' =>$productID,
            ];
        
        $prepare->execute($params);
        $fetchProduct = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $calculateTotalPrice = number_format($productQty * $fetchProduct['price'],2);
        
        $cartArray = [
            'product_id' =>$productID,
            'qty' => $productQty,
            'sku' => $entraSku,
            'color' => $entraCor,
            'medida' => $entraSize,
            'product_name' =>$fetchProduct['product_name'],
            'product_price' => $fetchProduct['price'],
            'total_price' => $calculateTotalPrice,
            'product_img' =>$fetchProduct['img']
        ];
        
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart_items']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart_items']))
        {
            $productIDs = [];
            foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $cartKey => $cartItem)
            {
                $productIDs[] = $cartItem['product_id'];
                if($cartItem['product_id'] == $productID)
                {
                    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$cartKey]['qty'] = $productQty;
                    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$cartKey]['sku'] = $entraSku;
                    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$cartKey]['color'] = $entraCor;
                    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$cartKey]['medida'] = $entraSize;
                    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$cartKey]['total_price'] = $calculateTotalPrice;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!in_array($productID,$productIDs))
            {
                $_SESSION['cart_items'][]= $cartArray;
            }

            $successMsg = true;
            
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['cart_items'][]= $cartArray;
            $successMsg = true;
        }

    }


    $pageTitle = 'Cool T-Shirt Shop Single Product Page';
    $metaDesc = 'Demo PHP shopping cart get tenis_femininos from database';
    
    
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://glarza.com/favicon.ico.webp" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">  
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"> 
<title><?php echo (isset($pageTitle)?$pageTitle:'PHP Shopping Cart')?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo (isset($metaDesc)?$metaDesc:'Demo PHP Shopping Cart')?>">
    
    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    

    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.stormize.com/framework/99571.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">

                                                    
<!-- FUCTION PELO TYPE BUTTON --><!-- FUCTION PELO TYPE BUTTON --><!-- FUCTION PELO TYPE BUTTON --><!-- FUCTION PELO TYPE BUTTO

//-->
    function switchVisible() {}
</script>

    

<style type="text/css">

#selectable img {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
.selected-items {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  line-height: 32px;
}   
</style>    
        
    </head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-2 mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <h1>
                    Cool T-Shirt Shop
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
               
            </ul>
            <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
               
            </div>
            
        </nav>
   
<?php     //ESTE É O PHP DO CHECKOUT COM ALGUMA MODIFICAÇÕES PRA FUNCIONAR AQUI;
   

       //pre($_SESSION);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['rua'],$_POST['bairro'],$_POST['cidade'],$_POST['uf']) && !empty($_POST['first_name']) && !empty($_POST['last_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['rua']) && !empty($_POST['bairro']) && !empty($_POST['cidade']) && !empty($_POST['uf']))
        {
           $firstName = $_POST['first_name'];

           if(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false)
           {
                 $errorMsg[] = 'Please enter valid email address';
           }
           else
           {
               //validate_input is a custom function
               //you can find it in helpers.php file
                $firstName  = validate_input($_POST['first_name']);
                $lastName   = validate_input($_POST['last_name']);
                $email      = validate_input($_POST['email']);
                $telefone   = validate_input($_POST['telefone']);
                $cep   = validate_input($_POST['cep']);
                $rua    = validate_input($_POST['rua']);
                $numero     = validate_input($_POST['numero']);
                $complemento     = validate_input($_POST['complemento']);
                $bairro    = validate_input($_POST['bairro']);
                $cidade      = validate_input($_POST['cidade']); 
                $uf    = validate_input($_POST['uf']);

                $sql = 'insert into orders (first_name, last_name, email, telefone, cep, rua, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, uf, order_status,created_at, updated_at) values (:fname, :lname, :email, :telefone, :cep, :rua, :numero, :complemento, :bairro, :cidade, :uf, :order_status,:created_at, :updated_at)';
                $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
                $params = [
                    'fname' => $firstName,
                    'lname' => $lastName,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'telefone' => $telefone,
                    'cep' => $cep,
                    'rua' => $rua,
                    'numero' => $numero,
                    'complemento' => $complemento,
                    'bairro' => $bairro,
                    'cidade' => $cidade,
                    'uf' => $uf,
                    'order_status' => 'confirmed',
                    'created_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'updated_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ];

                $statement->execute($params);
                if($statement->rowCount() == 1)
    
    $pageTitle = 'Demo PHP Shopping cart checkout page with Validation';
    $metaDesc = 'Demo PHP Shopping cart checkout page with Validation';
    
   
?>


    <?php if(isset($getProductData) && is_array($getProductData)){?>
        <?php if(isset($successMsg) && $successMsg == true){?>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <img src="<?php echo $imgUrl ?>" class="rounded img-thumbnail mr-2" style="width:40px;"><?php echo $getProductData['product_name']?> is added to cart. <a href="cart.php" class="alert-link">View Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         <?php }?>

        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img src="<?php echo $imgUrl;?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h1><?php echo $getProductData['product_name']?></h1>
                <p><?php echo $getProductData['short_description']?></p>
                <h4>R$<?php echo $getProductData['price']?></h4>
                <div class="selectable">

<?php include('layouts/select.php');?>

                        
                
            </div>
        </div>
       


<div class="row mt-3">
    
                                                                  
            </div>
       
       <?php
    }
 ?><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="js/custom.js"></script> </div><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script></body></html>
```

the product page has an php include

```php
<?php include('layouts/select.php');?>
```

I need to include the file layouts - colors and specific measures for each product:

```
layouts / id1.php
layouts / id2.php
layouts / id3.php
```

This is my layouts/selects file:

```php
<? php

  $id = echo $getProductData['id'];

if($id['acc']=='1') {
include('layouts/id1.php');}

if($id['acc']=='2') {
include('layouts/id2.php');}

if($id['acc']=='2') {
include('layouts/id3.php');}

?>
```

echo I get each product id

```php
<?php echo $getProductData['id']?>
```

My problem ... I need to insert this id inside this include file.

```php
<?php include('layouts/select.php');?>
```

or insert the id value in the specific php include, for example id = 1

```php
<?php include('layouts/id1.php');?>
```

So I want to open the include file by selected id. Of course if there is another solution I accept it :)

Comment: When you include a script within another script, the included script will have access to any variables defined in the script where it's included. They share their scope.

Comment: `$id = echo $getProductData['id'];` is not how you assign values to other variables. This will raise a syntax error.

Comment: Instead of `if($id['acc']=='1') {include('layouts/id1.php');}` you can simply do `include('layouts/id' . $getProductData['id'] . '.php');`. That way you wont need a conditional block to call the layout file.

Comment: Thanks  for any help!! The better way... I wont need a conditional block to call the layout file. But the include is not working.  My Best regards ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

include("layouts/id".$getProductData['id'].".php");

?>
```

Comment: Eh, this is the better way !! I wont need a conditional block to call the layout file. But the include is not working.  My Best regards ...